# One legend for two or more charts (g.raphael js)

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, raphael, pie-chart

I want to create two or more diagrams that share a single legend. When a sector is selected on any of the diagrams, the corresponding legend item should stand out. How to do this?

```
pie2 = r.piechart(545, 440, 25, [0, 22.22, 22.22, 11.11, 44.44]);
pie = r.piechart(490, 540, 25, [0, 0, 12.5, 25, 62.5], {
  legend: ["-20%", "21 - 40 %", "41 - 60 %", "61 - 80 %",
    "81 - 100 %"
  ],
  colors: ["#475664", "#8C5F66", "#DB7369", "#F29961", "#F0B165"],
  legendpos: "west",
  legendothers: "Others",
});
pie.hover(function() {
  this.sector.stop();
  this.sector.scale(1.1, 1.1, this.cx, this.cy);
  if (this.label) {
    this.label[0].stop();
    this.label[0].attr({
      r: 7.5
    });
    this.label[1].attr({
      "font-weight": 800
    });
  }
}, function() {
  this.sector.animate({
    transform: 's1 1 ' + this.cx + ' ' + this.cy
  }, 500, "bounce");

  if (this.label) {
    this.label[0].animate({
      r: 5
    }, 500, "bounce");
    this.label[1].attr({
      "font-weight": 400
    });
  }
});

pie2.hover(function() {
  this.sector.stop();
  this.sector.scale(1.1, 1.1, pie2.cx, pie2.cy);

  //?????
  pie.labels[1].stop();
  pie.labels[1].attr({
    r: 7.5
  });
  pie.labels[1].attr({
    "font-weight": 800
  });

}, function() {
  this.sector.animate({
    transform: 's1 1 ' + pie2.cx + ' ' + pie2.cy
  }, 500, "bounce");

  //??????
  pie.labels[1].animate({
    r: 5
  }, 500, "bounce");
  pie.labels[1].attr({
    "font-weight": 400
  });

});
```

Comment: I've clarified the question and beautified the code to help future visitors.